# Android Youtube API: how to play video when YoutubeView is invisible

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I'm trying to play Youtube Video with the  [Android Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/). I use the YoutubePlayerFragment and add it to a view container. It works well when the view container is visible. Then I tried to make the view container invisible. It stops working and throws an error "YouTube video playback stopped because the player's view is not visible". I'm wondering is there anyway I can play the video with the view invisible?

Answer (score 1):

**It's not possible**, even if you try to do some tricks.

This is because the SDK monitors all the view tree for the current `Window` and is therefore able to see if something is placed over the YouTube video container.

Comment: Is there anyway for us to trick the monitor? we trick the monitor to believe the video container view is VISIBLE.

Comment: To do that, you would need to decompile the SDK's JAR (which is obfuscated), locate the code that performs the check over the view tree and see **if** the code can be modified via Reflection (which is very unlikely). There's little to none chance of success, unfortunately.

Comment: I've tried all possible scenarios.Sometimes you cannot even a play a video properly(pauses every 2 seconds) despite it being the only view on the screen. You would be better off with another player and the youtube data apis.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. We can setAlpha(0.01f) of the view container for YoutubePlayerFragment. In this way, Youtube API is tricked to believe that the view is still VISIBLE.

Answer (score 0):

The Samle my Problem, but i have solved this with this code.

I initialized 2 variables :

```
public class VideoPlay extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
        YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView ;
        YouTubePlayer _YouTubePlayer;
```

This function change your `VIDEO_ID`

```
public void ChangeVIDEO_ID(YouTubePlayer player, String keyID){
    player.cueVideo(keyID);
}
```

I have a `ListView` in `LinearLayout`, when I click an Item in `ListView` something like this:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ChangeVIDEO_ID(_YouTubePlayer, mang.get(position).key);
        }
});
```

My `onInitializationSuccess()` was changed below:

```
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    _YouTubePlayer = player;
    if (!wasRestored) {
        Bundle bu = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bu != null) {
            String keyID = bu.getString("key");
            _YouTubePlayer.cueVideo(keyID);
        } else {
            _YouTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
        }

    }
} }
```